# How to get the mac address of a removed bluetooth device?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

The only ones I see are the added devices. How to get the mac address of the removed device(s)?

Comment: check the logs for the MAC address when the device was added

Comment: Can you edit your post to specify what you do in order to "see" the MAC addresses of the added devices?